# Problem with Firebase database rule ("Read" denied; Values get deleted automatically)

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

This is my database rule :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users' Input History": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }    
  },

    "Users' Vocabulary List": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to grant read and write access to those with an authenticated uid (user). Each user can only see his own created values under the "$uid" node, and cannot see values submitted by other users. However, upon simulation, an error came up saying: "Read" is denied. Below is the screenshotof when I ran the simulation:
[image: simulation screenshot]

Below is may database node structure:

```
{
  "Users' Input History" : {
    "TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2" : {
      "-M-eylUaQcCpoyTLwbhk" : "fate"
    }
  },
  "Users' Vocabulary List" : {
    "TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2" : {
      "-M-eyxRLoCpDftWQ4cDn" : "hardliner"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the values (which are "fate" and "hardliner") were manually added to the database by me via the firebase console, just in order to show you an idea of what I want my database to look like.
The actual situation is,
When I submit a value (for example "fate") to the database via my phone app, the following chunk of lines do appear in the database for a split second, but then immediately was deleted (or disappeared) automatically:

```
"Users' Input History" : {
    "TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2" : {
      "-M-eylUaQcCpoyTLwbhk" : "fate"
    }
  }
```

And the same goes for when I submit the value "hardliner".
So it turns out that, given the current database rule, new values would appear and then quickly disappear in my database, which renders my database rule pointless.

---

Here are the codes for authentification and pushing values to the database.

My activity for signing in:

```
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_sign_in);

                (some uncritical codes omitted here)


                GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();

                mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            }


            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(currentUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    try {
                        // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

    //The mDetailTextView will display the user's unique uid and the become the variable "username" which will later be used to push values into the database.                            
    username = mDetailTextView.getText().toString();

                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            }


            private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
                showProgressBar();

                AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
                mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    updateUI(user);
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    updateUI(null);
                                }

                                hideProgressBar();
                            }
                        });
            }

            private void signIn() {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }


private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user != null) {
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.Firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));
        } else {
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);
        }
    }
```

My activity for pushing values to the database:

```
public static DatabaseReference mRootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    public static DatabaseReference mChildReferenceForInputHistory = mRootReference.child("Users' Input History");
    public static DatabaseReference mChildReferenceForVocabularyList = mRootReference.child("Users' Vocabulary List");

searchKeyword = wordInputView.getText().toString();


Query query = mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).orderByValue().equalTo(searchKeyword);

                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });

                mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).push().setValue(searchKeyword);



mChildReferenceForInputHistory.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildKey) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

---

I've tried to explain the situation as much as I could but I have completely no clue on how to begin to pinpoint the cause and resolve the problem. Could anyone help?

Comment: "However, upon simulation, an error came up saying: "Read" is denied." Please edit your question to show a screenshot of the simulation you ran. Especially important will the path that you read from and the authentication details you specified, so make sure that those are visible in the screenshot.

Comment: Hello and thanks, Frank. I added the screenshot and I suppose it is what you meant?

Comment: `Query query = mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username)` This looks weird, as your database seems to use the UID to identify (and protect) user data, while in the code you use a value that the user enters in a text box.

Comment: The database uses uid for each username. I've updated my post and added the updateUI() helper method. Note these two lines: (1) mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.Firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));  (2) username = mDetailTextView.getText().toString(); . The getUid() will fetch the user's uid which will become the String "username".  As for this line: searchKeyword = wordInputView.getText().toString(); , "wordInputView" is an EditTextview for users to input a word, and the word will become the String "searchKeyword" pushed to the database as a value under the "$uid" node.

Comment: Actually, before I wrote this post, I tried using the default database rule, which is {
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
} , while using the current sign-in and push value codes you see now in my post. Everything worked fine, meaning that the disppearance problem didn't occur, until I began to change the database rule to the screenshot you see in my post. So I thought my code wasn't problematic and maybe it was because I wrote the rule wrong. Perhaps there is something wrong with my code and I don't know yet.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) again, as user inputs (and outputting things to the UI) make the code much harder to parse, then simple hard-coded values and logging statements. E.g. `mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).orderByValue().equalTo("fate")...`, especially if you then log `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` right before that line, so that we can see that it has an expected value.

Comment: At this point it may be time to hit the reset button on this question. It went from "I get this error in the simulator" (which I tried to answer), to something quite different (although undoubtedly related to the same problem for you), and I'm still not sure what line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do, and it's getting hard to parse through all the history here. I recommend opening a new question, where you post the [minimum, complete code+rules+data that any one of us can run to reproduce the exact problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read the root of your database. This means that Firebase checks whether the current user has read permission at the root. Since you didn't sign in, this user will only have read permission if your rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true
  }
}
```

And since you don't have such a rule, the read operation is rejected.

---

If you want to be able to read data in the simulator, be sure to toggle the Authenticated button, and give the user a UID that is present in your JSON (such as `TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2`).

But even with that you won't be able to read from the root. You're not granting anyone `.read` permission on the root, and by default all reading is disallowed.

The important thing to keep in mind here is that rules do not actually filter the data. They are merely used by the database server to check whether a read operation is allowed. So if you try to read from the root, and don't have read permission on the root, the read operation is rejected completely.

Since you only allow users to read their own node in your security rules, you should read that exact path in the simulator. So if you set the authenticated user to `TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2`, then the read path would be something like:

```
/Users' Input History/TdtIwvAPewRr1l9HY67PfkLBPbn2
```

This also means that if you want to read both the `Users' Input History` and `Users' Vocabulary List` for a specific user, you will need two read operations.

Comment: That explains the "read denied" problem. Does that also solve the "automatic disappearance" problem?

Comment: Typically if you briefly see data on the client that writes it, and it then disappears, that means that the security rules rejected that write operation. To be able to better help with any of this, share the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce the issue](;http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv). That's the most efficient way to allow us to help you, as it now seems that my trying to help you with your simulator problem is not actually what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Frank. I update my post with some codes for signing in and pushing values.